# Why is `x && return` invalid?

Tags: javascript

I know that you can do this:

```
function first(a){
    a && console.log("true");
}
```

which is the same as:

```
function first(a){
    if(a){
        console.log("true");
    }
}
```

However, when I tried this:

```
function first(a){
    a && return false
}
```

It doesn't work, and it throws me an error. Why is it giving me an error?

Comment: Better yet, use `if` for control flow, and `&&` for logical and.

Comment: Your first two examples have the same effect, but they aren't really the same because `a && console.log("true")` is an expression which returns a value (you just don't use the value in this case).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`return` can only be used in a statement on its own.

In `a && return false` it would be part of an expression, which is syntactically wrong.

Comment: ...because as opposed to `console.log(...)`, `return` is not a function call and consequently it is not an expression since it does not produce a value

Comment: Which is the difference between keywords that are operators and keywords that are statements - things like `new` are ok inline because they are Expressions, where as statements like `return`, `break`, `continue` - those are a block-level.

Comment: I made my answer a community wiki. Feel free to add your remarks. You both are right.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to do it that way, you can do something like

```
return a && false || undefined
```

or for missingno's sake,

```
return ( a && false ) || undefined
```

Since `&&` takes precedence over `||`, it will be evaluated first - but parens are cool, and are always down to party.

Also, check out the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf - page 68 shows you how expression operators (like `new`) differ from statements like `return` (page 93)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the effect you want by putting the return in the start of the line:

```
return a && console.log("true");
```

`return` is part of a [statement](http://es5.github.com/#A.4) and cannot be placed in a place that expects an expression (like the operand of a logical operator).

Comment: I am not returning `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

The first one only works because && is a short-circuit logical AND, this means it is only true when both expressions are true

So, if A evaluates to true (i.e., A is not null, undefined or an empty string), it will also have to check if console.log("true") is true, thus calling the method

If A is false, the expression will be false, so there's no need to call method (short-circuit)

To make it clearer, if you do

```
A & console.log("test")
```

test will be logged no matter what A`s value is

The second does not work because it's an statement on it's own... It's the same of trying

```
if(A && return false) {
    //doesn't work
}
```

The correct way would be

```
return A || B;
```

This would return B if A evaluates to false

Comment: _"If A is false, the expression will be false"_ - if A has a falsy value the expression will return A (otherwise it will return the other operand). So if A is, say, "" the expression will return "", not false.

Comment: @nnnnnn, you're right, but that's not what I was trying to explain. I meant to explain that && is a short-circuit operator, and when the first evaluates to false, the entire expression will be false, thus not evaluating the second